# Problemas com VBA

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Boa tarde, estou com esse problema para rodar um programa criado em VBA, já tentei reinstalar a biblioteca MSCOMCTL, porém não funcionou, alguém sabe de alguma ajuda relacionada ?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi Lucas! Tudo bem? Por favor, poderia disponibilizar o código para poder nos auxiliar a te ajudar? Obrigada!

Comment: Olá. Você está usando uma ListView?